# AllAuth support for python 3.4 and django 1.8.2?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-allauth

I want to integrate my django appln with facebook. I'm using python 3.4 and django 1.8.2.

AllAuth official documentation says it's compatible with python version 3.3 and 2.7.
Has anybody integrated allauth package with python 3.4 and django 1.8.2?

Are they compatible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3.4 is supported, with Django 1.6 and above. For reference, see the Travis build matrix over at: https://travis-ci.org/pennersr/django-allauth/builds/69339608

Comment: Is it compatible for allauth version 0.21 or I've to install dev version? Though, I've installed allauth and started integrating it.. but facing some errors